# Docker swarm constantly shuts down containers

Tags: ubuntu, docker, docker-swarm, linode

I have created a docker swarm manager node on 3 machines - one windows 10 machine and 2 Ubuntu machines. Things are working as expected on windows 10 and one of the Ubuntu machines. However on the last machine (Ubuntu 16.04, a virtual one on Linode) after installing everything, following the instructions [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/#install-using-the-repository) and using the docker-ce version 17.06.0~ce-0~ubuntu I am not able to start any service or stack properly - all of the service/stack containers shutdown in a second. No logs from the containers themselves - they seem to be stopped immediatelly after they have started. If the restart_policy is set to on-failure containers start and shutdown like crazy. Replicas are set to 1 (default). Starting any service and then checking services status with

```
docker service ps *service-name*
```

shows an error in the rightmost column

```
starting container failed: suвЂ¦
```

Other than the swarm docker run works just fine -

```
docker run hello-world
```

produces the desired output. So do any other containers started via docker run.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue is the fact that Linode is using by default their own signed kernels, which are causing issues for other people too. This was revealed because when inspecting the stack network most options seemed to be set to null. A further search suggests that there is an issue with Linode's kernels which causes the swarm networking to fail.

To prevent any such issues you can just use the default kernels by editing the machine in question and setting its kernel to GRUB2. Lots of helpful info [here](https://forum.linode.com/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=13995&sid=cdfdc9b766eb7266719e210b4d24c339).